# Azure CustomScript not being executed on start

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

I am running a VMScaleSet with Ubuntu instances.

Also I have a customScript extension set up in terraform like this:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set_extension" "customScriptExtension" {
  name                         = "my-cs-ext"
  virtual_machine_scale_set_id = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set.vmss.id
  publisher                    = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                         = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version         = "2.0"
  settings = jsonencode({
    "commandToExecute" = "sh init.sh"
    "fileUris" = ["storageurlToDownloadfrom/foo.txt?sas_token"]
  })
}
```

This kinda works, as everythin gets provisioned, and the VMSS is running fine. But the `customScript` is not being executed automatically after starting the VMSS.

I always have to manually press the "upgrade" button for the selected VMSS-instances, **then it works** (means the commandToExecute is being executed).

I need to have this script run automatically when a new instance starts, as this is especially relevant for scaling out the vmss.

I expected the customScript to be used for exactly this and in Videos I watched, the customScript was executed automatically. At least I have seen this working for VMs, not yet for VMSS, but there shouldn't be a difference, right?

Hope anyone can help me :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you make any changes in VMSS by default you need to upgrade the VMSS nodes with the most recent configuration **MANUALLY for Flexible orchestration**. Refer below:-

***When I selected the Orchestration mode as Flexible by default manual upgrade was selected like below:-***

[image]

[image]

> If you want your VMSS to update automatically, You can create a VMSS instance in an orchestrated mode selected as Uniform by referring the code in this official [terraform
> document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine_scale_set) below:- As the
> [document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine_scale_set) itself states :- NOTE: As of the  **v2.86.0**  (November 19, 2021)
> release of the provider this resource will only create Virtual Machine Scale Sets with the  **Uniform**  Orchestration Mode and enable automatic update with the block below:-
>
> ```
> {
>
> name  =  "example-vmss"
>
> resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.name
>
> location  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.location
>
> sku  =  "Standard_F2"
>
> instances  =  1
>
> admin_username  =  "adminuser"
>
> upgrade_mode  =  "Automatic"
>
>   
>
> automatic_os_upgrade_policy {
>
> enable_automatic_os_upgrade  =  true
>
>
> disable_automatic_rollback  =  true
>
> }
>
> health_probe_id  =  azurerm_lb_probe.example.id
> ```

**On Portal:-**

***I created one Uniform orchestrated VMSS and enabled automatic update like below:-***

[image]

[image]

Added ***the custom script extension to install Azure CLI*** like below:-

[image]

Now, ***When I logged into my VMSS instance the az module was automatically reflected without a need to do it manually upgrade*** refer below:-

[image]

> Reference:-
>
> https://medium.com/microsoftazure/vm-scale-set-with-a-local-azure-custom-script-pushed-via-terraform-c4196329657a
> By  James Dumont le Douarec

Comment: Indeed, `upgrade_mode  =  "Automatic"` did the trick. Thanks :)